# File -> ../../archive/folder/file restore

Tags: files, symlink, mv

Hi i'm new to Linux and I need to use it temporary to set up LetsEncrypt. Once complete, I needed to move the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem` file into the root dir but i moved the file incorectly:

`mv fullchain.pem /fullchain`

and then it showed up in my root as red fule `fullchain` so :

`mv fullchain fullchain.pem`

and something gone totally wrong. It appears to be a shortcut. The old file is gone.

[image]

How can I rescue the file or get it back? Is the permission wrong? because the `live` folder is totally not accessible true the file browser but accessible true term with `sudo -i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file stills there. You only changed the file's path and name since you only execute `mv` and not `rm` command. Your original file must be in `/fullchain.pem`.

You moved the `fullchain.pem` file from its original path `/etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem` to `/` that's why you can't see it any more in the main.

Just execute `$ mv /fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/`

Comment: I don't understand how this worked. Thanks.